# How to replace replace Html.Raw text with ASP.NET Identity user data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to replace content in my post body, I am using a WYSIWYG editor. I am entering the text "Placeholder" and trying to replace it with ASP.NET Identity user data in my controller.

I have an extension method for ASP.NET Identity:

```
public static string GetUserFirstName(this IIdentity identity)
{
    var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(identity.Name));

    return user != null ? user.FirstName : String.Empty;
}
```

This is my create action in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Image,TypeId,ModalName,Title,Description,Body,CreatedAt")] Document document, HttpPostedFileBase Image)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // set timestamp
        document.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.Body))
        {
            document.Body.ToLower().Replace("Placeholder", User.Identity.Name);
        }

        //extract first three characters of the document title as the Id for the modal pop up
        document.ModalName = document.Title.Substring(0, 3);

        db.Documents.Add(document);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // redirect to index page
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.DocumentTypes, "Id", "Type", document.TypeId);
    return View(document);
}
```

This is the view

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@item.Title" aria-hidden="true" id="@item.ModalName">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Raw(item.Body)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by replacing the text with the values of the identity extension methods, in the Index action result of the controller.

```
document.Body = document.Body.ToString().Replace("BusinessName", User.Identity.GetBusinessName().ToString());
document.Body = document.Body.ToString().Replace("UserEmail", User.Identity.GetBusinessEmail().ToString());
document.Body = document.Body.ToString().Replace("UserAddress", User.Identity.GetUserAddress().ToString());
document.Body = document.Body.ToString().Replace("UserPhone", User.Identity.GetContactNumber().ToString());
```